# How do I show non-standard characters in the address bar?

Tags: character-encoding, html-entities

I have a bugging problem. For a website I made there are search engine friendly URL's generated. The only problem is there are ß-chars in the url too. Chars like ö, ï, ä, ü etc. are placed correct. But with the ß-char there is a diamond-icon with a questionmark in it.

I thought it had to do with the charset which is used but i've tried both UTF-8 and iso-8859-1. Both without luck.

I need to have the correct character in the url for the readability of deeplinks.

Comment: "there is a diamond-icon with a questionmark in it" where? Browser address bar? Web page links?

Comment: In the URL, addressbar. it's this icon: �

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2887733/212218

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem with `iconv` function.